# Vue.js add isActive to class name within a v-for and dynamic class names in the bind

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have the following looping through some data in store.js Which is all working great I however want to add the vue is active condition to the class for the polygon, however I cant work on the syntax without breaking note.content_type, which provides the dynamic class name.

once I can set { active: isActive } on this element I think I know how to add this to my data and change it on a tap or click.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="800" id="space" ref="sheets">
          <g
            v-for="(note, index) in notes"
            :key="'note'+index"
            :transform="`translate(${note.xpos}, ${note.ypos})`"
            class="draggable"
          >

            <polygon
              v-if="note.content_type == 'link'"
              points="9.500000000000002,16.454482671904334 -19,2.326828918379971e-15 9.499999999999986,-16.45448267190434"
              fill="#989898"
              :class="note.content_type"
              :id="note.id"
            />

          </g>
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry just edited - uses the array syntax not an object:

```
<polygon
  v-if="note.content_type == 'link'"
  points="9.500000000000002,16.454482671904334 -19,2.326828918379971e-15 9.499999999999986,-16.45448267190434"
  fill="#989898"
  :class="[ note.content_type, isActive ? 'active' : '']"
  :id="note.id"
/>
```

Comment: yes I just realised I need to use the Array not Object approach - thanks

Comment: thank you, now to work out where I should best put the isActive thing without causing to many headaches

Comment: You could create a function which takes the note object and works out a bool value and returns it to the :class binding?

Comment: Thanks all good, In the end I have added a new value into my store and passed back the value from the component

Comment: Fair enough, nice :)